# Animate SVG <filter> with <animate> in React

Tags: html, reactjs, animation, svg

I am trying to animate a shadow defined by a `<filter>` using `<animate>`.
The animation should start on a `mouse enter` event.

Unfortunately the animation already starts even before I move the mouse over the element.

I found [this](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dPRVqL?editors=1010) example in pure **HTML**:

```
<filter id="dilate">
    <feMorphology id="morph" operator="dilate" radius="0" />
</filter>
<animate 
  xlink:href="#morph"
  id="anim-dialiate" 
  attributeName="radius"
  from="40"
  to="0"
  dur="3s"
  fill="freeze"
/>
```

and would like to implement something similar in React. Unfortunately I can't see an effect.

**EDIT:** My whole **React Component** where I use `<animation>` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PatternNode(props) {
    function handleOnMouseEnter() {
        props.handleOnMouseEnter(props.data.id)
    }

    function handleOnMouseLeave() {
        props.handleOnMouseLeave()
    }

    return (
        <g
            onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={handleOnMouseLeave.bind(this)}
        >     
            <filter id="node_filter" height="130%">
                <feDropShadow 
                    id="node_shadow" 
                    dx="1" 
                    dy="1" 
                    stdDeviation="1" 
                    floodColor="gray" 
                    floodOpacity="0.8" 
                />
            </filter>
            <animate
                xlinkHref="#node_shadow"
                id="animate_node_shadow"
                attributeName="stdDeviation"
                from="0"
                to="0.8"
                dur="3s"
            />
            <circle 
                cx={props.data.x} 
                cy={props.data.y}
                r={props.styles.radius}
                fill={props.data.color}
                filter={props.selected ? "url(#node_filter)" : ""}
            />
        </g>
    )
}
```

**EDIT:** `floodOpacity` seems to be not animatable. Therefore I animate `stdDeviation` but now have the problem that I the animation starts before the mouse enters the element.

Comment: Please add a more complete code showing how you used the filters.

Comment: You've two elements with the same id, that's likely also a problem.

Comment: I corrected the syntax errors and provided the whole code. It is still not working :( Also if I remove the mouse enter functionality it still doesn't work. Is this even possible in React. Never saw a similar example.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax errors:

1. `id` in the code must be unique
2. Instead of `xlinkHref` there should be`xlink: href`
3. In the name `ID` there should not be a hyphen`id = "node-shadow"`since the SVG perceives it as a minus and the animation does not work. Correctly writing `id =" node_shadow "`

Below is an example of an animation of the `dx` filter attribute.
 Animation starts when you hover

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="800" height="250" viewBox="0 0 800 250" >  
 <defs>
  <filter id="filter_shadow"  height="130%">
    <feDropShadow 
        id="node_shadow" 
        dx="1" 
        dy="1" 
        stdDeviation="1" 
        floodColor="gray" 
        floodOpacity="0.8" 
    />
</filter>
</defs>
   <path id="path1" fill="#39cb58" d="M332.8,20.3c-40.4,0-73.2,32.8-73.2,73.2l-0.1,1.6c0,51.3-41.6,93-93,93s-93-41.6-93-93l0-1.6c0-40.4-32.8-73.2-73.2-73.2l0-19.8c51.3,0,93,41.6,93,93l0,1.6c0,40.4,32.8,73.2,73.2,73.2s73.2-32.8,73.2-73.2l0.1-1.6c0-15,3.6-29.2,9.9-41.7C265,21.4,296.5,0.5,332.8,0.5V20.3z" filter="url(#filter_shadow)">
     
  </path>
    <animate id="animate_node_shadow" xlink:href="#node_shadow"  attributeName="dx"   values="1;3"  begin="path1.mouseover"  dur="1s" fill="freeze"/> 

   
</svg>
```

**animation `stdDeviation`**

in the code changes only the attribute  attributeName  = "stdDeviation"

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="800" height="250" viewBox="0 0 800 250" >  
 <defs>
  <filter id="filter_shadow" width="130%" height="130%">
    <feDropShadow 
        id="node_shadow" 
        dx="1" 
        dy="1" 
        stdDeviation="1" 
        floodColor="gray" 
        floodOpacity="0.8" 
    />
</filter>
</defs>


   <path id="path1" fill="#39cb58" d="M332.8,20.3c-40.4,0-73.2,32.8-73.2,73.2l-0.1,1.6c0,51.3-41.6,93-93,93s-93-41.6-93-93l0-1.6c0-40.4-32.8-73.2-73.2-73.2l0-19.8c51.3,0,93,41.6,93,93l0,1.6c0,40.4,32.8,73.2,73.2,73.2s73.2-32.8,73.2-73.2l0.1-1.6c0-15,3.6-29.2,9.9-41.7C265,21.4,296.5,0.5,332.8,0.5V20.3z" filter="url(#filter_shadow)">
     
  </path>
    <animate id="animate_node_shadow" xlink:href="#node_shadow"  attributeName="stdDeviation"   values="1;5"  begin="path1.mouseover"  dur="1s" fill="freeze"> </animate>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: `xlinkHref` is correct [JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes).

Comment: I think the hyphen isn't a problem, but I corrected it anyway and also provided a unique ID. Still not working :( I also provided more code.

Comment: @oezguensi 1. The floodOpacity animation does not work for me either, so in my example I chose other filter attributes for animation 2.be a hyphenid = "node-shadow" the animation also does not work, checked before writing and read about it in other sources

Comment: @Alexandr_T you are correct floodOpacity indeed doesn't work whereas stdDeviation worked for me. Unfortunately now I have the problem that the animation already starts even before the filter is added to the node on mouse enter.

Comment: @oezguensi the CSS mapped attribute you want is flood-opacity, not floodOpacity

Comment: @RobertLongson no, because it is in React :)

Comment: @oezguensi I know but is React smart enough to fix the attributeName value in the animate tag?

Comment: floodOpacity doesn't work at all. I didn't check if flood-opacity in HTML is animatable. But in React stdDeviation indeed works, whereas std-deviation doesn't.

Comment: @oezguensi flood-opacity animation does work in the underlying platform i.e. if you write native javascript and don't use React, at least it does in Firefox.